# Adding a checkbox to cxGridDBColumn (DateEdit)

Tags: delphi, devexpress, tcxgrid

I using Delphi BDS 2006 and have a DevExpress cxGridDBColumn with properties set to DateEdit and was wondering whether it is possible to add a checkbox to the displayed date time picker popup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a quick hack which should help you implement this feature.  However, you should handle the checkBox yourself.  I have done this for the standalone editor, however, the same approach will work with the inplace editor:

```
procedure TForm1.cxDateEdit1PropertiesPopup(Sender: TObject);
var
  AEdit: TcxDateEdit;
  ACalendar: TcxPopupCalendar;
  ACheckBox: TcxCheckBox;
begin
  AEdit := TcxDateEdit(Sender);
  if AEdit.Tag <> 1 then
  begin
    AEdit.Tag := 1;
    ACalendar := TcxPopupCalendar(AEdit.Properties.PopupControl);
    ACheckBox := TcxCheckBox.Create(Self);
    ACheckBox.Parent := ACalendar.Parent;
    ACheckBox.Align := alBottom;
    ACheckBox.Transparent := True;
    ACalendar.Parent.Height := ACalendar.Parent.Height + ACheckBox.Height;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure that I understand what you wish to achieve.  Anyway, it is impossible without creating a custom cxEditor which supports this look&feel and desired functionality.

Comment: Hi, what I want to achieve it to have a cxGrid where one of the columns uses a date selector (DateEdit). I want the usual calendar drop down to be displayed but at the bottom have an embedded checkbox.

Comment: Here is a quick hack which should help you:

procedure TForm1.cxDateEdit1PropertiesPopup(Sender: TObject);
var
  AEdit: TcxDateEdit;
  ACalendar: TcxPopupCalendar;
  ACheckBox: TcxCheckBox;
begin
  AEdit := TcxDateEdit(Sender);
  if AEdit.Tag <> 1 then
  begin
    AEdit.Tag := 1;
    ACalendar := TcxPopupCalendar(AEdit.Properties.PopupControl);
    ACheckBox := TcxCheckBox.Create(Self);
    ACheckBox.Parent := ACalendar.Parent;
    ACheckBox.Align := alBottom;
    ACheckBox.Transparent := True;
    ACalendar.Parent.Height := ACalendar.Parent.Height + ACheckBox.Height;
  end;
end;